# Likelihood ratio test and critical region

Tags: hypothesis-testing, inference, likelihood-ratio

I'm not really understanding some theoretical passages about the LRT used for composite hypothesis test.

I know that the LRT

$\lambda_{01}(x_n)=\frac{sup_{\Theta_0}L(\theta;x_n)}{sup_{\Theta}L(\theta;x_n)}$

is used as a test statistic to determine the critical region. Now, suppose that we have a casual sample of a normal model $N(\theta,\sigma^2)$, with known $\sigma^2$ and that we want to perform this test:

$H_0 : \theta\leq\theta_0$ vs $H_1 : \theta>\theta_0$

Since it is a normal distribution, we know that:

$\lambda_{01}$ = $\frac{sup_{\theta\leq\theta_0}L(\theta;x_n)}{L(\theta_{MLE}; x_n)}$ = $\frac{sup_{\theta\leq\theta_0}L(\theta;x_n)}{1}$ = ${sup_{\theta\leq\theta_0}L(\theta;x_n)}$

because we know that in this case $\theta_{MLE}=\bar{X_n}$

Now we have to distinguish between two cases:

$\lambda_{01}(x_n)=
\begin{cases}
L(\theta_{MLE};x_n) \: \:\  \:\: \theta_{MLE}<\theta_0 \\
L(\theta_0;x_n)     \:\: \: \:\:\:\:\:\:\:\    \theta_{MLE}>\theta_0
\end{cases}$

That is to say:

$\lambda_{01}(x_n)=
\begin{cases}
1 \: \:\  \:\: \:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\theta_{MLE}<\theta_0 \\
L(\theta_0;x_n)     \:\: \: \:\:\:\:\:\:\:\    \theta_{MLE}>\theta_0
\end{cases}$

Here's my doubt: my theory book says that the critical region is built upon the second equation  of the system in this way:

$R=\{x_n\in\chi^n\::\:\lambda_{01}(x_n)<k\}$

and so

$R=\{x_n\in\chi^n\::\:L(\theta_0;x_n)<k\}$

I don't "graphically" understand why it just considers the second equation and not the first one: I know that it would be just $k>1$ and that it would not be much sense, but I still don't get why. If there were a case in which the two equations are not simple numbers, which one would I be supposed to choose?

Thank you.

Comment: When $\lambda=1$, we trivially accept $H_0$.

Comment: And can there be a case in which those two equations (better, one of them) are not constant values? What happens in that case?

Comment: Which two equations?

Comment: Those of the LRT system $\lambda_{01}$, I've always dealt with the normal case and our teacher has not talked much about the other cases yet, but in general can this happen? Which one to choose then?